# Issue using Epic Games Launcher in Lutris in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, games, 32-bit, lutris

(Linux noob here running Lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 32-bit) I installed Lutris 0.5.6 on my pc and then install the latest version of Epic Games Launcher from the Lutris website. When I ran Lutris and double-clicked the Epic Games Launcher. The following error appeared...[image] I don't know what this means. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix might be to uninstall Epic Games store in Lutris and reinstall it.

You can report this bug to the Lutris developers, they maybe able to help:
https://github.com/lutris/lutris

Also check following link to make sure that Lutris and its dependencies are correctly installed:
https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/HowToDXVK.md